# How to decode Redis responses in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, redis

I would like to receive decoded responses from redis in my flask application.

When I'm using `redis.hget` for example, I receive

```
{
    b'a': b'1',
    b'b': b'2',
    b'c': b'3',
}
```

That's not really ideal for my use case, since it requires me to use the has list like so `my_hash[b'a']`.

I'd rather receive responses like this:

```
{
    'a': '1',
    'b': '2',
    'c': '3',
}
```

Is there a simple way to have python-redis decode all responses from the data store?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply make a small custom provider that sets the `decode_responses` argument when the data store is configured using the `from_url` function.

```
class DecodedRedis(StrictRedis):
    @classmethod
    def from_url(cls, url, db=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs['decode_responses'] = True
        return StrictRedis.from_url(url, db, **kwargs)


redis = FlaskRedis.from_custom_provider(DecodedRedis, app)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `decode_responses=True` to get str not byte

here are my code use factory mode

```
from flask_redis import FlaskRedis
redis_store = FlaskRedis(decode_responses=True)
def create_app():
    redis_store.init_app(app)
```

you could like this

```
>>> from app import redis_store
>>> redis_store.keys()
['test']
>>> redis_store.hgetall("test")
{'a': '1'}
```